# Using the same solver for real and imaginary matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matlab

If I want to solve a matrix equation like $Ax =b$,  where $A$ is
 $n \times n$ matrix and real, and   $b$ is a real   vector  which has a length $n$, $x$ is the solution for  the linear equation. I solved the above equation by using that solver  $Ax =b$.

What if $A$ is $n \times n$ matrix and complex, and   $b$ is a complex   vector  which has a length $n$. Can I use the same strategy?

**EDIT:**

We can find the solution of x by finding the inverse of A.

```
B= inv(A)
```

And therefore

x =A^{-1}b.

```
x= B*b
```

Can i apply the same solver if A and b are complex?

Answer (score 0):

> What if A is $n×n$ matrix and complex, and $b$ is a complex vector which has a length $n$. Can I use the same strategy?

Yes, if your method is Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: @SabbirHasan The usual way of solving such matrix equations is called Gaussian elimination. If you got a computer to solve it for you, that would also be the method it used. And it also works with complex numbers.

Comment: To elaborate: it depends on the structure of the matrix. In general the algorithm will probably use the $LU$ decomposition (a variant of GEM). If the matrix has some special propeties (i.e. it's hermitean) and the solver checks for that it might choose a more efficient method. Many, but not all, will work with complex matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has a help page in case you need some help. The following link contains the help page to 'system of linear equations' solvers.
[Matlab help page for system of linear equations](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop). More specifically, it shows you what algorithm is used depending on the matrix $A$ (since $Ax = b$ also works for over determined systems, in which case you will get a least squares approximation). Note that this method is more reliable then manually inverting the matrix $A$, since this takes much more computational time!

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ I assumed you want to solve equations using matlab, since you tagged this question with 'matlab'.